# Is there a way (json/xml) for importing content from a 3rd party site into seperated WP posts?

Tags: xml, json, import, wordpress

As anyone has any experience with it? tried to do the same?

Many thanks.

Comment: ¿The 3rd party site is also a Wordpress site?

Comment: No.. It could be Yahoo, BBC, ESPN or any other site that I will be able to import content from it using XML, JSON or some other technique if you know..

Comment: Well the only way I know when there is no access to the back-end area of the external site,  is through RSS feeds. There are some WP plugins that handle that method pretty well.

Comment: Which plugins? Is there a plugin that doesn't require to convert in into CSV? Is there a plugin that separates the XML into different posts? THanks.

Comment: The RSS (Really Simple Syndication) feeds are indeed in XML format. Some plugins will fetch them and display them. I don't know if there are some that also convert them into posts, but look for them and check `/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php` That's the class (Simplepie) usually used for that purpose. Most news and similar sites allow other sites to replicate their content as long as the respective credit is included, by the way.

Comment: I am just trying to add some widget of another site like importing wheater, finance, news, etc. I don't understand what's wrong about it, and many site do that and still by google, the original content will be first. @s_ha_dum

Comment: If anyone, has a link or experience doing it, so I can learn to do it myself, it will be appreciated. @FelipeAlamedaA thanks for your help. I'll check that.

Comment: And of course the feature I'll add will contain the source (credit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found is this and it is my answer for now:
SupraCSV
Wp Ultimate CSV 
CSV to Post

If you know anything else, I'd like to hear..
Many thanks!

Comment: WP RSS Aggregator's Feed to Post enables you to do just that. https://www.wprssaggregator.com/extension/feed-to-post/